# How to read ripple and noise on a linear power supply using RIGOL DS1202Z-e?

Tags: dc, noise

I am new and want to learn the right way to read noise and ripple from a linear power supply. In this case, I measured 5 V DC for a sample. I used 1 channel. I connected the center of the probe to +5 V and the shield of the probe to ground. Here is what I got:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually the probe 'needle' itself is not referred to as the centre. Your grounding clip should not be connected to -5V, unless you are referring to ground. What kind of power supply is this(linear or switching)? As it currently is, your question lacks enough information to be answered.

Comment: @lemon Yes, it was my mistake.  It is ground. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: How are you grounding the scope probe? Are you using the ground lead on the probe or connecting the ground ring to system ground? If you're using the probe ground lead, you will possibly get an inaccurate picture of the noise. Show a picture of your measurement setup.

Comment: I'd like to know where and how you're probing this. I'm suspecting that you're not grounding your probe properly and its behaving as an antenna that's picking up A LOT of noise.

Comment: Most likely the ground lead forms a loop antenna that picks up either a noise from nearby high-power switcher or even from a local FM broadcast station :-)

Comment: The first assumption about it being a linear power supply is likely wrong, and the noise is switching noise from a switch mode power supply. Also the supply looks like to have a 2-prong mains inlet, so expect to see common mode noise.

Comment: @qrk  and Colin I checked all channels are connected to earth ground. I tried to use coil spring like antenna. I got 100mv per division. peak to peak is 200mV. It was much better then using ground clip. I tried to upload picture of probe setup with coil spring, but somehow it does not let me. Did I setup my scope correctly both menu on the screen and probe?

Comment: @Justme I opened up the power supply. There were 2 transformers and capacitors. Would like you tell me how to find out the type of power supply?

Comment: @Henry I bet there are not 2 transformers, and the other thing you think is a transformer is not one. Show a picture of the supply board. How to find out? Well, from experience, the size of the supply, you just can't make a 50W+ dual linear supply with that size, and it can also take 100-240V supply range in. All signs of switch mode supply.

Comment: @Justme Thank you. I will find out more about switch mode supply. I can't see everything on PCB because it has a big aluminum cover it. Did I setup everything correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the connections are wired correctly, but the arrangement is poor.

So like what you did, by connecting probe ground clip and scope tip to power supply ground and supply pins are correct.

However, the loose wiring makes a big loop and the loop of wires is right on top of the switch mode supply, so it will pick up interference.

Usually ripple and noise are measured in a specific setup which you often see in many places.

You have no load, but the load is optional, you can measure the ripple and noise at any load you want. The results may just vary while the load is varied too.

The usual setup is to have some capacitance at the end of power supply cable where the scope probe connects. There is again no standard, but typically you might use a 10uF electrolytic for low frequencies and a 100nF ceramic capacitor for high frequencies.

The measurements are also usually done with limited bandwidth, and that is why oscilloscopes usually have a setting to limit a channel to 20 MHz bandwidth.

It must also match the correct probe settings, because 1x probes usually have very low bandwidth and you should use a 10x probe, or if the probe has a selectable setting, then use the 10x setting. As a rule of thumb, if you have a selectable probe, always use the 10x setting, unless you know you have a good reason to use the 1x setting.

Still, there might be switching noise seen on the scope that is really not there, because the power supply has a two prong mains inlet, and there must be a capacitive noise suppression "Y" capacitor between mains input and DC output. It may help to use an isolation transformer on the supply (never defeat ground on your equipment). Also the scope and all other equipment used that have a three-prong earthed mains inlet must be properly earthed by connecting the plug to a properly earthed mains socket.